# How to use a data like a image and song in android on Virtual Box from my computer?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, android

I installed Oracle Virtual Box on Windows 8. Then I downloaded Android-x86.

After I installed Android-x86 on Virtual Box from the ISO, and it working good but how to use a data like image and song from my computer to Virtual Box???

I have a data in my computer but I can't use this data in Android-x86 on Virtual Box.

What can I do to troubleshoot this or get start use data from my computer???

Comment: I see that *every* single question of yours so far has been duplicated on SuperUser and StackOverflow. Do ***not*** do this, and delete one of each copy (also before posting a question read what's on-topic for each site).

Comment: if you have a solution than give me no need to satiation

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "satiation", but every community has its rules and you need to play by them. You are persisting in duplicating questions on both sites even after being told not to do so.

Answer (score 2):

When using something in a VM, you always have to remember that conceptually it's like you have a separate system.  So, ask yourself, how would you get a file into Android-x86 if it was a separate system, like a phone or separate device?

If it was a phone, I'd install something like AirDroid or similar to transfer data via the web or your LAN.  The Android-x86 image you are using in a VM probably doesn't have an app store.

One thing you can do is run a local webserver (a quick and dirty one is [mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/downloads/list)) and then browse to your computer's IP on the LAN in the Android browser.  You can then navigate and download files into Android-x86 that way.

Otherwise, if there is some type of app you can install to allow network access into Android, you could try that route.  I am not familiar with Android-x86 and if you can install the same .apk's as an Android phone or tablet.  You could try installing the AirDroid .apk [here](http://www.androiddrawer.com/10807/download-airdroid-2-0-2-app-apk/#.UeHbsyQo5p8) by browsing to it from your Android-x86 image.

You may have seen "drag-and-drop" functionality on Virtual Box or VMware before.  This is possible under a Windows VM because VMware tools is installed within the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Take a pendrive and format with FAT32 and then copy your all data u want to open in android . Then start your machine and go to devices and in usb devices select your pendrive . It will run and show with the name [ usb0] :-)